# Why does using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in Version 8.0.3 results in failure when run migration with dotnet ef from .NET 8?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-migrations

Trying to create a migration with `dotnet-ef migrations add Initial`

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CloudBeholder.Identity.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'CloudBeholder.Identity.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

I am using SQLite. The packages related and their versions are in `csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My `ApplicationDbContext` and `InfrastructureExtensionCollection` bellow:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class InfrastructureExtensionCollection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection service)
    {
        service.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlite("Data Source=App.db"));

        service.AddAuthorization();

        service.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        return service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I confused the name of two packages that have very similar spellings, they are Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`. After replacing with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core` and running the migration, everything worked as expected.

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project ..\path\to\yourProject.csproj --context "ApplicationDbContext"
```